# Determine the measures of the angles of the face $VAB$.

Tags: geometry

*question*

$VABCD$ is a regular quadrilateral pyramid. An ant starts from point $A$ and still arrives at point $A$ (point $A'$ when we have the plane drawing), going along all the side faces. Knowing that the length of the path travelled is minimal and that the length travelled on face $VAB$ is twice that travelled on face $VBC$, determine the measures of the angles of face $VAB$.

*the drawing*

[image]

*my idea*

we let points $A=A'$ for the plane drawing

We unfold the $(VAB)$, $(VBC)$, $(VCD)$ and $(VDA')$ faces in the plan.

If $\angle AVB<45^{0}\Rightarrow\ \angle AVA^{\prime}<180^{\circ}$

In this development $AM+MN+NP+PA^{\prime}$ is minimal, if the points $A, M, N, P, A'$ are collinear, where $M\in VB$  $N\in VC$   $P\in VD$ .

We have $AM=2\cdot MN$

VABCD regular quadrilateral pyramid $\angle AVB\equiv\angle BVC\equiv\angle CVD\equiv\angle DVA^{\prime}\Rightarrow\angle A^{\prime}VC\equiv\angle AVC \Rightarrow VN $ bisectors in triangle $VAA'$

$VA\equiv VA^{\prime}\Rightarrow\Delta VA^{\prime}A$ isosceles with base $A^{\prime}A$ whence we get that  $VN \perp A'A$

With the bisector theorem in the triangle $VAN ⇒ \frac{VA}{VN}=\frac{AM}{MN}=2 => VA=2*VN$

With the reciprocal of the $30^{0}$ angle theorem in the right triangle $VNA$, $ \angle VAN = 30°, \angle AVN = 60°$

It is obtained that $\angle AVB=30^{\circ} , \angle VAB=\angle VBA=75^{\circ}$

I don't know what to do if $\angle AVB >45.$

For $\angle AVB =45.$, its easy because the points $V,A,A'$ are colinear.It is obtained that $\angle AVB=45^{\circ} , \angle VAB=\angle VBA=67^{\circ}30'$

Hope one of you can help me! Thank you!

Comment: 1/ Adding an image would be helpful, 2/ Why is $AM=2MN$? 3/ Towards the end I think you mean "don't know what to do if $\angle AVB > 45".

Comment: @CalvinLin I edited the post. $AM=2MN$, because  the length travelled on face $VAB$( this means side $AM$)
 is twice that travelled on face $VBC$ ,(which means $MN$)

Comment: K, looks good. For the $ > 45^\circ$ case, you basically show that the shortest path is going up on AV, touch the other faces, and back down VA again. So then the distance travelled on VBC is ~0.

Comment: @CalvinLin The thing is that this means that the distance travelled on $VBC$ is 0=> the distance travelled on $VAB$ is 0 which is false. Also, we have to show the measures of the angles of face $VAB$.

Comment: Right, so that case is not possible. IE You've found the only possible solution, which is the 30-75-75.

Comment: @CalvinLin Ooo, now I understand! I Thank you! have one more question, we put the condition $\angle VAB>45$.  What would be the maximum value this angle could get?

Comment: For a solid convex figure, angles at a point must sum to less than 360. So max angle is 90.

Comment: @CalvinLin After I looked over this problem again I realised that the case when $\angle AVB=45$ isn't right too. The minimum way is $AA'$, which makes the distance travelled on $VBC =0$=> the distance travelled on VAB
 is 0 which is false. Correct me if I'm wrong!

Comment: Yup, agreed with you.

Comment: @CalvinLin May I ask why the shortest path for $\angle AVB=45$ is going up on AV, and back down it? I tried proving it but failed. Thank you!

Comment: @IONELABUCIU Same question towards you.

Comment: @RyanPamMunoz Do you understand what OP is doing in the $ < 45^\circ$ case? If no, work on understanding it first. If yes, modify it to the $ = 45 ^\circ$ case and observe that $AVA'$ is a straight line (as OP wrote).